# SSIS Flat File to FTP

Tags: c#, php, csv, ssis, ftp

I have searched everywhere for this answer. I am setting up a Data flow task to pull Data from a table using a customer sql script, it then saves it as a flat file with dynamic naming called NMC Services_(Date Range). the issue is i need to take this one file and upload it onto an FTP Site but i continue to get one of 5 errors:
Error at Package: The connection "FilePath\NMC Service Requests_0606-0612.csv" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.

Error at FTP Task [FTP Task]: For the FTP operation "Send", the FILE connection manager "File Path\NMC Service Requests_0606-0612.csv" can not be found.

Error at FTP Task: There were errors during task validation.

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

using a variable or expression doesn't change it. The file writes to the file path but does not go out and grab it.

This isn't copied it is built from scratch.

When using a variable i get this

Error at FTP Task: Failed to lock variable "File Path\NMC Service Requests_0606-0612.csv" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".

Error at FTP Task: The Validate method on the task failed, and returned error code 0x80131500 (Failed to lock variable "File Path\NMC Service Requests_0606-0612.csv" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".
). The Validate method must succeed and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.

Error at FTP Task: There were errors during task validation.

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

I have rebuilt the whole Package from scratch over and over again and still have the issue.

Comment: Break the problem into units.  Which unit is breaking?  The most obvious to me without having access to your solution is that the file is not found.  Are you sure it exists?  What is `File Path`?

Comment: The error messages are all the same root cause.  The connection was not  completed.  Why is your SERVER Name a filename? "The connection "\joey.stellar.local\home\jschultz\NMC Service Requests_0606-0612.csv" is not found."  The connection should be a server name but it is a CSV file.

Comment: Yes because im trying to upload a file to the ftp site. The file is created and placed in that directory and then im trying to move it to the ftp site

Comment: Kyle, File path is the path to the CSV File. It does exist as the Data flow task pulls and creates the file and places it using the file path.

Comment: John, are expressions for the file name in play? The reason I am asking is because if a concatenated variable hasn't had a chance to fully build, an in-common root portion could conceivably throw the "lock variable" message you're seeing.

Comment: I have tried with variable and without. With variable I had it delay validation until it executed that package. If its not fully building the variable then what would i need to do?

Comment: I even used the variable with the send mail option to add the file as an attachment and it worked. It just doesn't seem to work with FTP Task

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. I am using an expression to determine the name of the file that it is needing to send. When I set up the variable I put the file path to the file as the value, and then setting evaluate as expression true. I erased the value and placed the expression i use to dynamically name the file in the variable properties under expression and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help!